# Tracking down high latency in Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, transactions, kafka-consumer-api

I have Kafka setup in an admittedly slow configuration - but I'm not expecting the numbers I'm seeing.

I have the cluster set to `LogAppendTime`, so I'm measuring the time between the event is written to Kafka (as decided by the broker) and the time its received by the service. Both the brokers and the application are "co-located" so the ping time between the servers is low and the clocks should be sync'ed or close to it.

I am seeing latencies between `2ms` and `600ms`, alot are `250ms`+...the massive difference makes me think something is up with my setup. It varies between consumer groups also.

`Kafka v2.7.0` x 4 brokers

Key broker properties:

```
default.replication.factor = 4
min.insync.replicas = 2
num.partitions = 50
offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
offsets.topic.replication.factor = 4
transaction.state.log.min.isr = 2
transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 4
```

Key consumer properties:

```
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
isolation_level = read_committed
```

Key producer properties:

```
enable.idempotence = true
linger.ms = 0
transaction.id = <id>
```

I'm using a transactional producer to commit the offsets with `producer.sendOffsetsToTransaction()`.

There are many consumer groups, all of which are transactional and operate in the same way of reading events, then committing new events along with the new offset.

Are there any settings I'm missing? I know Kafka isn't geared towards low latency but I want to setup to achieve the lowest latency I can...hopefully < `20ms`.

**EDIT**

I've also tried with these settings:

```
default.replication.factor = 2
min.insync.replicas = 1
num.partitions = 50
offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
offsets.topic.replication.factor = 2
transaction.state.log.min.isr = 1
transaction.state.log.num.partitions = 50
transaction.state.log.replication.factor = 2
```

Without using transactions and

```
enable.idempotence = false
```

Comment: can you try removing transactions and then measure the latency? i have seen increased latencies for kafka transactions. This might help us understand if tuning can be made specific to transaction related settings.

Comment: @RishabhSharma - even with transactions off, I can still hit `> 120ms`...just doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: did you measure end to end latency? producer + consumer?

Comment: change `isolation.level` to `read_uncommitted `, and test.

Comment: @nipuna - Yeah this is end-to-end latency. Changing the isolation.level had minimal impact.

Comment: can you measure producer and consumer latency separately?

Comment: @nipuna - it would appear to be consumer latency that is the problem.

Comment: I have a sneaky suspicion that this could actually be the producer `sendOffsetsToTransaction` call.

Comment: Create simple consumer and producer with basic configuration and check latencies. Then continue adding features like idepotence and transactional and check latency. Then you can find exact point where latency begins.

Comment: @nipuna - its the `sendOffsetsToTransaction` call which is causing the latency. Because consumption is single threaded and this is a blocking call, it means that the next `poll()` is delayed which makes it look like its consumer latency, but it's actually the stated call that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`num.partitions = 50` and `offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50`, the number of brokers is 4. I believe that is causing an issue as your cluster is spending a lot of time doing replication and fetching replicas so time is spend in network communications. Also the I/O threads would be limited causing issues.

Reduce the number of partitions if possible. Is there a reason to have 50 partitions on a 4 node cluster?

Suggest you play with the following settings

- num.network.threads
- queued.max.requests.
- num.io.threads.
- num.replica.fetchers.

Comment: I'll be honest, I just used the defaults for these two. How does the number of partitions affect replication speed...I assumed Kafka would be fetching data for multiple partitions in one call...was I wrong?

Comment: @Cheetah - I thought so as well. Each partition needs to be replicated and if there are a lot of partitions to be replicated they take up network and IO bandwidth. Try reducing the number of partitions and then bump up the four parameters(in the above).

If you donot get any improvement then bump up the parameters in the above answer.